# No route matches [POST] "/companyrating/index"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

I am newbie to ruby on rails. I am getting this error. I have followed this tutorial http://www.codelearn.org/ruby-on-rails-tutorial/forms-form_tag-params-attr_accessible-model-validation
 for the form posting. But when I click on submit i was getting an error

this is my 
controller

```
class CompanyratingController < ApplicationController
  def index
     @companies = Companyrating.all
  end


 def add
   #companies.create(:companies => params[:name, :place, :rate, :rank])
   #redirect_to :action => 'index'
    @companies = Companyrating.new(params[:name])
  if @companies.save
    flash[:success] = "Welcome to My Space!"
    redirect_to root_url
   end
 end

end
```

this is modal

```
class Companyrating < ActiveRecord::Base
    attr_accessible :name, :place, :rate, :rank

end
```

this is my routes file

```
get "companyrating/index"
match "companyrating/add" => "todos#add", :via => :post
```

my index file

```
<title>Shared Todo App </title>
<h1>Shared Todo App</h1>
<p>All your todos here</p>
<ul><li> <% @companies.each do |t| %>
  <li> <%= t.companies_name %> </li>
  <li> <%= t.companies_place %> </li>
  <li> <%= t.companies_rate%> </li>
  <li> <%= t.companies_rank %> </li>
<% end %>
  </li></ul>

  <%= form_for("@companies/add", :method=>"post") do |f| %>


      <%= f.label :name %>
      <%= f.text_field :name %>

      <%= f.label :place %>
      <%= f.text_field :place %>

        <%= f.label :rate %>
      <%= f.text_field :rate %>

      <%= f.label :rank %>
      <%= f.text_field :rank %>
       <%= f.label :user_id%>
      <%= f.text_field :user_id %>

      <%= f.submit "Save changes", class: "btn btn-large btn-primary" %>
    <% end %>
```

This was my error: No route matches [POST] "/companyrating/index"

can anyone help me in solving this error

Comment: Is it possible you also have a method: "post" in your link to your index file? you declared it in your routes file as a "get"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem you're having is two-fold - with your `routes` and `controller actions`

I know Monk_Code gave an answer, but since you're new, I'll explain how it all works for you, with the goal of helping you understand the system a bit better:

---

**Routes**

Your first issue is to do with your routes

Rails has done an amazing job of creating great routing structures, and the core of this is the idea of [`resourceful` routes](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#resources-on-the-web)

By using the following code, your Rails app creates a series of 7 routes which Rails uses to send "default" traffic to your controller actions:

```
#config/routes.rb
resources :companyratings
```

This routing structure creates the following routes in your app:

> - new [GET]
> - index [GET]
> - create [POST]
> - edit [GET]
> - update [POST]
> - destroy [DELETE]
> - show [GET]

All of these routes take directed traffic, and *routes* it to the relevant controller action. This means that if you send a user to `/companyratings/`, it's going to load the `index` action, likewise `/companyratings/15` will *show* the show action in the controller

On top of this, you also need to know what the HTTP "verb" does. This is a key principle which Rails uses to route your traffic accordingly. The "verb" in your request is the type of request that's sent, and is dependent on the browser

As you can see from the list above, every route has an associated HTTP verb. The reason why this is important is because if you send a `[GET]` request to a route which only works with the `[DELETE]` verb, you're going to get a problem, hence why you're seeing errors when you send a `[POST]` request to your `index` action

You should read the [Rails tutorial](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#resources-on-the-web) on this, as you can either fix the issue by sending the correct HTTP verb (using `:method => :get`), or specify the `[POST]` verb in your `index` action route

---

**Controller Actions**

Controller actions are the function defined in your controller, which are loaded when you run a particular request in Rails

The default index actions are listed above, but you can also have any others you like, as long as you provide the correct routes. Your problem is that you've just used the `add` action, where you should have used the `create` action:

```
class CompanyratingController < ApplicationController
  def index
     @companies = Companyrating.all
  end

 def new
      @companyrating = Companyrating.new
 end

 def create
  @companies = Companyrating.new(new_company_rating)
  if @companies.save
    flash[:success] = "Welcome to My Space!"
    redirect_to root_url
   end
 end

 private
 def new_company_rating
      params.require(:company_rating).permit(:variables, :listed, :here)
 end

end
```

Comment: thanks you so much for your explanation. but still i got this error First argument in form cannot contain nil or be empty in my index page that  <%= form_for (@companyrating) do |f| %>  I could not understand the problem

Comment: That error means you have not declared the @companyrating variable in the `new` action. I have edited my answer to help -- look at the `new` action code :)

Comment: @RichPeck thx!. to user3130393 do not be lazy to read the documentation there are all described in detail

Comment: You should look up more about [Rails Instance variables](http://www.railstips.org/blog/archives/2006/11/18/class-and-instance-variables-in-ruby/) (variables with @ before them)

Comment: No problem @Monk_Code, I find a lot of people don't understand why a problem happens, hence why they need help fixing

Comment: @RichPeck Thank you for your help and kind nature.  but still it is the same error I am getting.

Comment: Can you post the error in your question? According to your question, I believe both @Monk_Code & my solutions *should* work, but as with many things in life, there'll likely be something else preventing it from happening. If you can post the full error, it will help tremendously

Comment: This is my error
ArgumentError in Companyrating#index

Showing /home/seshendra/rails_app-master/app/views/companyrating <%= form_for (@companyrating)  do |f| %> /index.html.erb where line #12 raised:

First argument in form cannot contain nil or be empty

Comment: Okay I know what the problem is. You're calling the form from the `index` action. To make this work, you need to add the `@companyrating = Companyrating.new` to your `def index` action in your controller

Comment: But still I m unable to post my data to database it was showing me this error 
uninitialized constant CompanyratingsController

Comment: thank you @RichPeck  for your help I have understood some working methodology. thank you

Answer (score 1):

in controller:

```
def new
  @companyrating = Companyrating.new
end

def create
  @companies = Companyrating.new(params[:companyrating])
  if @companies.save
    flash[:success] = "Welcome to My Space!"
    redirect_to root_url
  else
    flash[:error] = "Can't create companyrating."
    render 'new'
  end
end
```

in routes.rb:

```
resources :companyrating
```

in form:

```
<%= form_for(@companyrating, method: :post) do |f| %>
```

Comment: this the error The action 'show' could not be found for CompanyratingController

Comment: thank you I have tried that but still I was getting an error at the index file. First argument in form cannot contain nil or be empty